# How to I convert reflect.New's return value back to the original type

Tags: go, reflection, go-reflect

I'm using reflection in `go` and I noticed the oddity expressed below:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
        a int
        b int
}

func main() {
        t := reflect.TypeOf(Foo{})
        log.Println(t) // main.Foo
        log.Println(reflect.TypeOf(reflect.New(t))) // reflect.Value not main.Foo
}
```

How can I convert the `reflect.Value` back to `main.Foo`?

I've provided a [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qUcYpnP5iB) for convenience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the [`Value.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) method to get an `interface{}`, then you can use a type assertion to extract value:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(Foo{})
val := reflect.New(t)
newT := val.Interface().(*Foo)
```

If you don't want a pointer, you use the [`reflect.Zero`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero) function to create a zero-value for the type. You then use the same interface and type assertion method to extract the new value.

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(Foo{})
f := reflect.Zero(t)
newF := f.Interface().(Foo)
```