# Restore type information after passing through function as "interface {}"?

Tags: go

I'm running into a slight architectural problem with Golang right now that's causing me to copy/paste a bit more code than I'd prefer. I feel like there must be a solution, so please let me know if this is perhaps possible:

When I pass things through an `interface {}`-typed function parameter, I start getting errors such as "expected struct or slice", etc. ... even though what I passed was previously a struct or a slice. I realize that I could manually convert these to another type after receiving them in that function, but then that become tedious in instances such as this:

> local interface type *interface {} can only be decoded from remote
>   interface type; received concrete type

... In this case, the receiving function seems like it'd need to be hard-coded to convert all `interface {}` items back to their respective original types in order to work properly, because the receiving function needs to know the exact type in order to process the item correctly.

**Is there a way to dynamically re-type Golang `interface {}` typed variables back to their original type?** Something like this, [How to I convert reflect.New's return value back to the original type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098936/how-to-i-convert-reflect-news-return-value-back-to-the-original-type) ... maybe?

---

**EDIT:** To clarify, basically,  I'm passing `&out` to a function and it needs to be its original type by the time it reaches another inner function call.

Example code:

```
// NOTE: This is sort of pseudo-Golang code, not meant to be compiled or taken too seriously.

func PrepareTwoDifferentThings(keyA string, keyB string) {
    var somethingA TypeA;
    var somethingB TypeB;

    loadFromCache(keyA, &somethingA, nil);
    loadFromCache(keyB, &somethingB, nil);

    fmt.Printf("Somethings: %v, %v", somethingA, somethingB);

}

func loadFromCache(key string, isNew, out interface {}, saveNewData interface {}) {
    if err := cache.load(key, &out); err!=nil { // NOTE: Current issue is that this expects "&out" to be `TypeA`/`TypeB` not "interface {}", but I don't want to copy and paste this whole function's worth of code or whatever.
        panic("oh no!");

    }

    if (saveNewData!=nil) {
        cache.save(key, saveNewData); // This doesn't seem to care if "saveNewData" is "interface {}" when saving, but later cache fetches above using the "load()" method to an "interface {}"-typed `&out` parameter throw an exception that the "interface {}" type on `&out` does not match the original when it was saved here (`TypeA`/`TypeB`).

    }

}
```

Comment: You can't convert to the original type without knowing what it is. Reflect can let you dynamically handle various types, but you can't get a "real" type without an assertion.

Comment: I just posted some clarification as an edit.

Comment: The current workaround I have is to pass a closure to the function instead of an `interface {}` type property, and the function calls that function if necessary without losing the original variable's type as it's within the prior scope and never changes type. However, this requires me to copy and paste code into various instances of me calling this method, which I find unnecessary.... Seems like the only way to keep the type that I've found.

Comment: Then yo need to assert it back to the correct type. If you know the signature of the function that needs to be called at compile time, then you know the type you need to assert. If not, you have to do the whole thing using reflection.

Comment: Posting the relevant part of the code might help.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'll post some code.

Comment: Posted code. Please let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: Read the link in [@TClaverie's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37498813/4475267). With that method, create a *new* variable with the type you want and the value of `out`.

Comment: ... Wouldn't it be better for me to just pass a type (not an empty struct) to this function then? How can I do that?

Comment: @noisypixy This isn't working. If I pass a `reflect.Type` typed property to a function there's no way to create an object of that type and populate it to return to the caller. Help? What are you saying?

Comment: `reflect.Type` can't be used as type assertion, it is a representation of the type, not the type itself. But you cannot store a Go type into a variable, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using `JSON` instead of `Gob` for serialization avoids the error that I was encountering entirely. Other functions can handle passing into interfaces, etc.

Comment: Please, post how you solved the issue then. However, serializing and deserializing structs in order to get the right type is not a good way to solve it. And, you still have the problem of getting back the right struct at the end.

Comment: That's not the issue really. It's more that the cache load/save methods in my example were panicking if an `interface {}` was passed versus a native type. Since the function might not have access to the original type in order to declare a wide range of possible types, I had to switch to `JSON` as the cache method which was less picky than `Gob`.

Comment: I ended up writing different store and load methods for my differently structured objects so I can explicitly specify the type of the objects being stored. That way you can still use gob.

Answer (score 5):

To change the type of an interface into its rightful type, you can use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
package main

import r "reflect"

type A struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    // No pointer
    aa := A{"name"}
    var ii interface{} = aa

    bb := ii.(A)
    // main.A

    // Pointer
    a := &A{"name"}
    var i interface{} = a

    b := *i.(*A)
    // main.A

    c := i.(*A)
    // *main.A

    d := r.Indirect(r.ValueOf(i)).Interface().(A)
    // main.A
}
```

[Playground 1](https://play.golang.org/p/wH_dwjb8yO)

When using type assertions, you have to know the underlying type of your interface. In Go, there is no way to use type assertion with a dynamic type. `reflect.Type` is not a type, it's an interface representing a type. So no, you can't use it this way.

If you have several type possibilities, the solution is the [type switch](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type TypeA struct {
    A string
}

type TypeB struct {
    B string
}

func doSomethingA(t TypeA) {
    fmt.Println(t.A)
}

func doSomethingB(t TypeB) {
    fmt.Println(t.B)
}

func doSomething(t interface{}) {
    switch t := t.(type) {
    case TypeA:
        doSomethingA(t)
    case TypeB:
        doSomethingB(t)
    default:
        panic("Unrecognized type")
    }
}

func main() {
    a := TypeA{"I am A"}
    b := TypeB{"I am B"}

    doSomething(a)
    // I am A
    doSomething(b)
    // I am B
}
```

[Playground 2](https://play.golang.org/p/P1IMmC13vj)

Comment: Can you explain how to directly fetch the original type of an `interface {}` element and reassert it to that type before passing it to another function? If so, I can accept this solution.